# Play Console showing daily installs of two different versions

Tags: android, google-play

I just checked out a weird statistics record in the Google Play Developer Console.

I was checking out the daily installs of my app which showed installs from two different versions ( 38 installs from Version Code 9 and 2 installs from Version Code 8).

[image: Screenshot showing daily installs from two different versions]

**I've published the latest version i.e. Version Code 9 on June 10** and **the records are of June 13.**

[image]

I want to know how can someone install a previous version of my app through play store.

As far as I know, play console only shows records of installs from play store and not from third party app stores or apk installations.

How is this possible then?

Comment: Maybe some users downloaded the older version's apk from mirror sites or transferred from friends via apk sharing app!

Comment: @suzanshakya if the app is not installed from Google Play, is it going to be count in Google Play statistics?

Answer (score 0):

This most likely is because of different timezones combined with some people possibly keeping the play store app "non-refreshed" in the background. Also the Play Store doesn't cache through all territories at the same time.

Comment: Even if I consider the timezone difference, you must notice that I published the latest version on June 10 and the records are of June 13. So I don't think it could be because of timezone difference as there is a difference of 3 days.